# Azure Data Factory pipeline - copy data from on-premises SQL Server and Dynamics CRM

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I need to transfer data from an on-premises SQL Server into CDS (Dynamics 365).
This can be achieved by in Azure Data Factory by using a CopyData activity, if all data to be transfered is already stored in SQL Server.
Unfortunately, this is not my case.
Steps for my requirement are:

- create a CRM record (parent record);
- the GUID of this record must be then included into the source data for CopyData activity.
  In fact, all the data transfered into CRM (by CopyData activity) need to be child records of the previous parent record.

How can I accomplish this data flow in Azure Data Factory, please?

Best regards,
Radu Antonache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookup and for-each activity in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, I thinks that lookup may be part of the solution.

Comment: Lookup solves my problem, I've done a query in CRM, order by Createon desc.